# REGEX Filter image name from a paragraph DOM

Tags: php, regex

I have this DOM in my site:

```
$question_data = '<p>Gambar di bawah menunjukkan ciri-ciri haiwan berikut:</p>

<p><img src="/uploads/images/questions/96_20160303124007.PNG" /></p>

 <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Beranak</td>
            <td>
            <p style="text-align: center;">Bertelur</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table> 
 <p>##a</p>';
```

This my REGEX to filter `96_20160303124007.PNG`:

```
define('GET_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION_PATTERN','/<img .*?src=(?:['\"])[^\"]*\/\K(.*?\.(?:jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:['\"]).*?>/');

$pattern = GET_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION_PATTERN;          

$arr_image_file_names = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $question_data, $arr_image_file_names);
```

But got no output... anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: [Required reading.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [common knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/165969) that regex is not the right tool for HTML parsing.

A solution without using regular expression:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($question_data);

$imgNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('img');

$arr_image_file_names = [];
for ($i = $imgNodes->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $imgNode = $imgNodes->item($i);
    $arr_image_file_names[] = pathinfo($imgNode->getAttribute('src), PATHINFO_BASENAME);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

change your constant to:

```
define('GET_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION_PATTERN', '/\d+_\d+\.(?:jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif|png)/i');
```